# Passing object reference inside of another object

Tags: javascript, ajax, oop, prototype, scoping

I'm declaring an object method in javascript.
Inside of this method I want to do an ajax call and, when the call is done, to modify some attributes of this object.

```
Bubble.prototype.draw = function(){

console.log(this.attribute) // -> works fine

var req = $.ajax({
url: "someFile.php",
type: "post",
data: someData  
});

// handle response
req.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){

console.log(this.attribute) // -> not in the scope, obviously

});

}
```

How can I put `this.attribute` in the scope of `req.done`? How can I access the whole `Bubble` object inside of `req.done`? Currently, all of my `Bubble`s are in an array so I could just pass in the index of this array and access the properties this way (`array[i].attribute`). I guess there is a much better way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried context:this, as ajax option? Not sure it works in this case

Comment: `this` needs to be saved in a variable somewhere outside the `$.ajax()` function. `var self = this;` then you can access `this` using `self`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it works like this, which seems the native way of doing it, using context option:

```
Bubble.prototype.draw = function () {

    console.log(this.attribute) // -> works fine

    var req = $.ajax({
        url: "someFile.php",
        type: "post",
        data: someData,
        context: this
    });

    // handle response
    req.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        console.log(this.attribute);

    });

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Bubble.prototype.draw = function () {
    console.log(this.attribute) // -> works fine
    var req = $.ajax({
        url: "someFile.php",
        type: "post",
        data: someData
    }),
        self = this; //save this object
    // handle response
    req.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(self.attribute) //access parent this
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because when the ajax callback is called the execution context is different, meaning the `this` keyword inside the callback method points to another object, not to the desired bubble object.

There are two solutions for this as shown below

Use $.proxy to pass a custom execution context to the callback handler

```
Bubble.prototype.draw = function(){

    console.log(this.attribute) // -> works fine

    var req = $.ajax({
        url: "someFile.php",
        type: "post",
        data: someData  
    });

    // handle response
    req.done($.proxy(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){

        console.log(this.attribute) // -> not in the scope, obviously

    }, this));

}
```

Or use a closure variable

```
Bubble.prototype.draw = function(){

    console.log(this.attribute) // -> works fine

    var req = $.ajax({
        url: "someFile.php",
        type: "post",
        data: someData  
    });

    var _this = this;
    // handle response
    req.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){

        console.log(_this .attribute) // -> not in the scope, obviously

    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

just copy `this.attribute` variable to another scope variable like this.

```
Bubble.prototype.draw = function(){

console.log(this.attribute) // -> works fine
_this = this.attribute;
var req = $.ajax({
url: "someFile.php",
type: "post",
data: someData  
});

// handle response
req.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){

console.log(_this) // -> not in the scope, obviously

});

}
```

Comment: you are setting _this in global scope, not the best method here